# Truffle not finding any functions (uncaught TypeError) or acknowledging debug commands (uncaught referenceError) on WSL

Tags: truffle, error, truffle-contract, windows, linux

I'm trying to get started with using Truffle but I keep running into issues with the SimpleStorage contract and getting Truffle to work. I'm able to deploy the basic SimpleStorage contract and do `x = await SimpleStorage.deployed()`, which returns a large JSON-like structure, but any further commands do not work. For example, `x.set(42)` returns `Uncaught TypeError: x.set is not a function.`

In the debugger, if I attempt to debug the deployment transaction, I'm told that any command I input is `Uncaught ReferenceError: <x> is not defined`

I'm using WSL, which I assume has something to do with the issue. Running truffle --version returns

```
Truffle v5.10.0 (core: 5.10.0)
Ganache v7.8.0
Solidity - 0.8.20 (solc-js)
Node v18.16.1
Web3.js v1.10.0
```

And for reference, the SimpleStorage contract I'm using is:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract SimpleStorage {  
  uint storedData;  

  function set(uint x) public {    
    storedData = x;  
  }  

  function get() public view returns (uint) {    
    return storedData;  
  }
}
```